# I'm getting 503 error instead of 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, server

When I append a random page name in my website's domain, The server returns: error 503 internal server error. Which is not the case. Because the requested page doesn't exist at all. For example:
When I type:
Www.mysite.Com/foobar.php
The server fires a 503 internal server error. Even though the foobar page doesn't Exist!!
Meanwhile, when I type foobar.html it gives 404 page not found error which is correct.
So how can I fix this? 
Thanks in advance.
Edit:
My problem is whenever I request a random page name from my website, it gives 503 error. which is wrong 
I want to make it so that when I request a none existing page, it gives error 404, not 503.

Comment: Huh? Set your scenario a little better and explain what is going on. Might refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/. Read your question as if you have no inside idea of what's going on.

Comment: Make sure you have apache set to interpret PHP files. You may need to either run it as an Apache module or using process manager like PHP-FPM. You can try http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php